# Play sound on button click?

Tags: android, media-player

i have got a method in my code to play music but it isn't quite working. Red underlining in one line... Here's my code:

```
public class MyActivity2 extends Activity {
private String[] colors;
private String[] values;
private TextView tv;
private RelativeLayout rl;
private MediaPlayer mp;
Button n;
int index = 0;
int position2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_activity2);
    n = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_view);

    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "BebasNeue Bold.ttf");
    n.setTypeface(typeface);
    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "OSP-DIN.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(face);

            values = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.allthings_array);
            colors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colorcode_array);

    n.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // mp = new MediaPlayer();
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pop);
            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mp.setLooping(true);
            mp.start();

        }
    });
            n.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            if (index == 5) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "More coming soon!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                position2 = (index++);
                            }
                            String textValue = values[position2];
                            tv.setText(textValue);
                            Random RAND = new Random();
                            int position = RAND.nextInt(colors.length);
                            String nextValue = colors[position];
                            rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(nextValue));
                            n.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(00, 00, 00, 00));
                            return true;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            n.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(00, 00, 00, 00));
                            return true;
                        default:
                            return false;

                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

At the line: mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pop); , (this, R.raw.pop) is underlined in red saying it can't resolve method..
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter in the `MediaPlayer.create()` method is the context. You can usually use `this` as the context when you're in an Activity class. The tricky part here, which is a common mistake with Android, is that `this` on that line refers to the `View.OnClickListener` you are defining. It's called an anonymous inner class.

You can solve this by changing the line to

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(MyActivity2.this, R.raw.pop);
```

Full OnClickListener (verified with my own mp3 raw file):

```
n.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MyActivity2.this, R.raw.pop);
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: No error in the code anymore, but I don't hear a sound when tapping the button?

Comment: I believe you need to call mp.prepare() before mp.start().

Comment: Er, if you are playing a sound from your `raw` directory, you don't need to stream it, right? What happens if you comment out `mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);`? Check out the docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mediaplayer

Comment: Still keep mp.prepare() ?

Comment: No, actually. My bad. You don't need to call it if you create the sound from a raw file. MediaPlayer.create() calls prepare for you automatically. You only need to prepare first when you are streaming from a remote URL.

Comment: These three lines work for me with my own mp3 file: `MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ball); mp.setLooping(true); mp.start();`

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like `mp = MediaPlayer.create(MyActivity2.this, R.raw.pop);` because you're doing it from an inner class and thus `this` refers to `onClickListener` and `MediaPlayer.create` method does not taks such argument.